# California housing prices dataset on Kaggle

Tags: dataset

This is the dataset I'm referring to: https://www.kaggle.com/camnugent/california-housing-prices

I am a bit confused regarding the dataset. Specifically, why is the number of houses not provided? We are given the number of households, but that's not equivalent to the number of houses. There's probably a near monotonic relation between the two, but I feel like the dataset should include the number of houses per block.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the dataset is aggregated from another raw dataset, e.g. the `mean house price` has been calculated from the raw data listing every house individually.

The creator of the dataset perhaps made a mistake, or intentionally left out the number of houses, perhaps not thinking this feature was relevant for the use-case in mind.

Either way, the dataset is made from **a census taken in California in 1990**, so perhaps you need to search for the **raw census data instead** and calculate it yourself.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it resolved your issue or let me know if something is unclear